# как собрать в список первое слово в каждой строке?

Tags: python

есть задание:

> "Создайте функцию `find_first_words`, которая в качестве аргумента
> использует путь до файла. Функция должна найти первое слово в каждой
> строке файла, и вернуть эти слова в виде списка.
>
> Если строка пустая, то функция возвращает пустую строку, т.е. `""`

мое решение не работает выдает в результате не список первых слов а первые буквы с переносом на другую строку. причем если не писать "+=" вроде как он правильно берет первое слово но исключительно только из последней строки как бы логично. но почему он тогда не добавляет через  запятую в одну строку все слова то??? должно получиться так:

```
['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'And']
```

а получается:

```
['F',
 'i',
 'r',
 's',
 't',
 'S',
 'e',
 'c',
 'o',
 'n',
 'd',
 'T',
 'h',
 'i',
 'r',
 'd',
 'A',
 'n',
 'd']
```

только между буквами символ переноса строки еще есть...(\n)

```
def find_first_words(input_file):
    # напишите здесь Ваше решение
    s= []
    with open(input_file,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            s +=line.split()[0]
    return s
```

а вот со вторым файлом не знаю как решить проблему
образец текста

```
"""I dont know

how do it 

im so sorry"""
```

исключение:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: плохая нновость ))) :
второй файл содержит пустые строки по условиям задачи в таком случае мы должны перечислить '' как это сделать ?

Comment: образец текста 

"""I dont know

how do it 

im so sorry"""
исключение:

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код:

```py
def find_first_words(input_file):
    result = []

    with open(input_file) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():  # перебираем строки файла
            if line != '\n':  # если строка не пустая ...
                result.append(line.split()[0])  # ... добавляем её в файл ...
            else:  # ... иначе ...
                result.append('')  # ... добавляем пустую строку

    return result
```

для входных данных

```
"""I dont know

how do it 

im so sorry"""
```

возвращает

```py
['"""I', '', 'how', '', 'im']
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

у  меня хорошие новости и плохие хорошие:
ответ на первую  часть задачи. в первом файле в каждой строке есть слово  первое  и я научилась его добавлять в список вот так:

```
def find_first_words(input_file):
s= []
with open(input_file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        t = line.split()[0]
        s.append(t)
return s
```

в итоге все выводиться верно: `['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'And']`

Comment: а плохих нет)))

Comment: есть выше добавила в сам пост там код потому что надо было дописать а в коменте нельзя так